# String from text document is not equal to the same string from the program

Tags: python

The goal of this code is to ask for a number 1-41, look up that particular number line in a text document, and check to see if it is equal to the string 'good'.

```
f = open("Goods", "r") #Opens the "Goods" file
lines = f.readlines() #Loads all 42 lines into memory

x = int(input("pick a number 1-41")) #asks for a number 1-41, casts it to an int, and assigns it to 'x'

if x < 13:
    goods = "Lumber"
elif x > 12 and x < 22:
    goods = "Spices"
elif x > 21 and x < 33:
    goods = "Fruit"
elif x > 32 and x < 41:
    goods = "Rum"
else:
    goods = "Opium"

if lines[x] == string:
    print("It worked!")
else:
    print(string, lines[x])  
#prints both the string, and the line gotten from the text document for trouble shooting
    print("Fail")
```

The problem with this code however, is that even though both the line from the text document, and the string 'goods' are exactly the same; python doesn't see that, and executes the else statement instead.

How can I get python to register both strings as the same?

Comment: try replacing lines[x] == string with lines[x].strip() == goods

Comment: Where do you set `string`?

Comment: `readlines()` keeps newlines, so `strip()` should do the trick

Comment: I think the reason you got downvoted is that you don't quite have an MVCE. In particular, you don't show where `string` and `goods` come from. Unnecessary to figure out this particular case, but it's good to provide an example that makes complete sense when possible.